# Why is an error event unhandled?

Tags: javascript, node.js, error-handling

I am pretty sure that the only place in my code that could be throwing this error, based on the port number, would be the following code.

```
try {
  webServer = new WebSocketServer({
    port: args.listen
  });
} catch (exception) {
  if (exception instanceof Error) {
    logger.log('Could not bind port ' + args.listen + ' for ' + args.name +', already in use.');
  }
}
```

I tried removing the `if` statement, but it did not change the result. When this runs if the port if already bound by a process I get the following error which I would like to catch and report without causing the process to exit.

> events.js:160
>         throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
>         ^
>
> Error: listen EADDRINUSE :::6010
>       at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:1020:11)
>       at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1043:20)
>       at Server._listen2 (net.js:1262:14)
>       at listen (net.js:1298:10)
>       at net.js:1408:9
>       at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:83:11)
>       at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:104:9)
>       at Module.runMain (module.js:606:11)
>       at run (bootstrap_node.js:383:7)
>       at startup (bootstrap_node.js:149:9)

Why would this not be caught by the `try...catch`?

Comment: You probably already checked it yourself, but is the error message really with this code? Is your try-catch in events.js on line 160?

Comment: The server is created asynchronously so the execution has long since left the try..catch block when the error is thrown.

Comment: What JJJ just mentioned is I think correct, it is due to the asynchronous behavior of JavaScript, besides that you need to monitor the events generated from the WebSocketServer. So WebSocketServer.onerror has to be written for this.

Comment: I suppose @JJJ that this makes sense, just not something I thought about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to try this. I think that is how we deal with websocket errors.

```
websocket.onerror = function(evt) {
            onError(evt)
         };
```